# Is there a possibility to kill the madman myself?

Tags: the-witcher-3

During the quest "Reason of State"

> the mad king Radovid gets killed

by Philippa Eilhart.

Is it possible to kill him myself? Or might there be a possibility that any other NPC gets the killing blow? (Vernon Roche or Ves for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately, the killing blow will always be given by Philippa. Well, she deserves the right to do it :)

Comment: Aw, man. Why does Vernon give my a lecture then when I cannot change the outcome? What a dick. ;-)